# Redis installation "make test" errors

Tags: redis

I am getting the following errors when running a "make test" for Redis 2.8 installation on CentOS 6.7:

```
*** [err]: Test replication partial resync: ok psync (diskless: no, reconnect: 1) in tests/integration/replication-psync.tcl
Expected condition '[s -1 sync_partial_ok] > 0' to be true ([s -1 sync_partial_ok] > 0)
*** [err]: Test replication partial resync: ok psync (diskless: yes, reconnect: 1) in tests/integration/replication-psync.tcl
Expected condition '[s -1 sync_partial_ok] > 0' to be true ([s -1 sync_partial_ok] > 0)
```

Are they fatal, and what can be done in order to resolve them? Thanks :)

Comment: Can I ask why you're compiling redis from source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something, however in my case forcing the task to be ran by only 1 processor did the trick:

```
taskset -c 20 make test
```

In the above I ran it on the 20th CPU. You can cat the /etc/procinfo file to get the number of CPUs you have and to determine which one to use.

Comment: yes this is an open bug : https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2715